# Refresh Parent Window From iFrame Pop-up

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I have an HTML page (index.htm) and a link in it. Clicking on that link opens a ColorBox iFrame (popup.htm) its a form with submit button.

Now when someone submits the form in that popup.htm page, I need index.htm to refresh automatically to -> index2.htm.

I have tried this and variations with no success.

```
<form onsubmit="window.opener.location = 'http://www.myDomain.com/index2.htm';">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `<form onsubmit="window.top.location.href = 'http://www.myDomain.com/index2.htm';">` Of course iframe and top must be on same domain and don't break same origin policy.